# GAS - Script to duplicate a script

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script

I have many buttons on my sheet, to hide and unhide some rows.

```
    function hide1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[2];
  sheet.hideRows(24,11);
}
function unhide1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[2];
 sheet.showRows(24,11);
}
```

I have also created a script to duplicate this sheet, in order to create a new one to be filled.

```
function clonemastersheet() {

  var sheetc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var getname = sheetc.getRange("t10").getValue();
  var name = getname

  var pp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mastersheet = pp.getSheetByName('Form0').copyTo(pp);
  mastersheet.setName(name)
  pp.setActiveSheet(mastersheet)
```

PROBLEM:
When it duplicates the new sheet buttons dont work because the macros are related to the first one.

I need to create a script that will be duplicated with the sheet and work with them.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you care about hiding them if they aren't the active sheet?

Comment: So you mean when you click on these new buttons it hides the rows in the first sheet?

Comment: If so modify the the sheet variable to this:. Var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet() in your hide1 and unhide1 function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function hide1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideRows(24,11);
}
function unhide1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 sheet.showRows(24,11);
}
```